# What is the difference between List and Collection in Snapi language?

Tags: list, code-snippets

I have two queries in snapi language:

`let hello = List.Build(1,2,3) in hello`

and

`let hello = Collection.Build(1,2,3) in hello`

They return the same result.

I run the queries but I don't see any difference, so I would like to ask, what is the difference between Collections and Lists.

Answer (score 1):

Collections are iterators that are processed on-demand, while Lists are similar to in-memory data structure.

Because a list is materialized, it is possible to access elements by position using the List.Get operation. This isn't possible for collections, since the only operation is to iterate over it.

Collections have a smaller memory footprint than lists, and in general should be preferred for larger datasets. Lists should be used when you don't want to recompute it every time (or when you need to access elements by index).

Because lists are materialized, a list can be in an error state. That is, it is possible to check if a list failed to compute. This feature does not exist for collections. Instead, a collection will fail only while it is being consumed.

In your example, there isn't much of a difference in practice. But if you have larger datasets, use collections when possible; if you want to avoid recomputation or need to access elements efficiently by position, use lists.